# Divide DD with DD in TASM (under DOS)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I have:
`V7 DD 0ABCDEFH`
`V4=-123`
`V5 DW -3, -7, 92`

I need to translate this stroke: `V7 /= V4 + V5[0]++`

AX and BX was used to split V7 (AX = 00ABH, BX = 0CDEFH)
CX and DX was used to store result of `V4 + V5[0]++`

There is my code:

```
;--------------------------
;V7 IS SPLITTED TO AX BX. AX = 00AB, BX = CDEF     
    ;V7 /= V4 +V5[0]  
    XOR DX, DX
    XOR CX, CX
    
    MOV DX, V4 ;DL = 85H
    
    INC V5[0] ;V5[0] = 0FFFEH
    
    ADD DX, V5[0] ;FFFE + FF85H
    ADC CX, 0
    
    ;CX DX -> RESULT OF V4 + V5[0]++
```

How can I resolve it and find solution?

Comment: The instruction you want for signed integer division is `IDIV`. Like all x86 instructions, it's described in detail in [Intel's manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html)

Comment: How I can store v7's value if AX already taken for it. I can't use other registers because they are already taken by other values. For dividing I should use AX and DX but I can't use tmp vars etc. Only with registers

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Load `V7` into `eax` and sign-extend it into `edx` with `cdq`. Sign-extend `V4` into `ebx` or `ecx`, divide, and then add `V5` to the result.

Comment: 16bit data bus.

Comment: Are you saying that you're going to run this on an 80286 or earlier that doesn't have 32-bit registers? If so, you should've stated that clearly in your question.

Comment: I think the goal here is to divide DD by DW, and that V5[0]++ should really be V5[index++], where index is initialized to 0, and the code run 3 times for the values, {-3, -7, 92}. See if you can verify what I am thinking from the class, and update the question if needed.

Comment: Are you supposed to do this in a way that can't #DE except for division by zero?  Or are you just supposed to put the dword in DX:AX and do 32/16 => 16-bit signed division which faults if the quotient doesn't fit in AX?

Comment: Can you show us the exact homework assignment (even if it is in russian?)